# nVidia graphic card seems not revelead by ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics, nvidia-settings

My laptop is an Asus f550c.

If I execute the command

```
lspci| egrep VGA
```

it prints

> 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core
>   processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)

like the detection of an nvidia card is missing.

I've installed the native driver nVidia. They are activated, but the driver manager says they are not currently used.

How to solve?

Answer (score 0):

In my honest opinion no, it's not normal.
I have a ASUS K53 with Nvidia geoforce GT 540 and that is my result (2 lines):

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09) 
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF108M [GeForce GT 540M] (rev a1)
```

Comment: I edited the question. Basically it seems that the driver even if activated are not used. How is that possible?

Comment: You could find your answer browsing the questions listed on the right side related to this topic.